# Error after deleting a component class only to make it an anonymous

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I had created a component with `artisan make:component` which creates both a class and a view. Later on, I thought of having the extra class just for properties is pointless so I deleted the class. But now I am getting `Failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error which tries to open the related class.

How can I fix this? How can I turn a class-based component into an anonymous one without getting errors?

I also removed the related classes from `autoload_classmap.php`.

Comment: try also clearing your `bootstrap/cache` directory

Comment: @apokryfos should I simply delete the files inside? I have checked the files' content but there was nothing related to the component. Are you sure that will fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. However they are cache files. They will be regenerated if deleted, so there's no harm in trying (keep the .gitignore file though)

Comment: I ran `composer dump-autoload` in my project folder and that fixed it.